# When I delete an item from the RecycleView, I delete the data from the Firebase Database, but the RecylerView is not updated. What should I do?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In my fragment named FragmentFavs, I get the data from Firebase and show it in the RecyclerView.

This is my model data class

```
data class NewsDBModel(
    val key : String? ="",
    val author : String? = "",
    var title : String? = "",
    val description : String? = "",
    val url : String? = "",
    val urlToImage : String? = "",
    val publishedAt : String? = ""

)
```

This is my FragmentFavs

```
class FragmentFavs : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var bind : FragmentFavsBinding
    private lateinit var arrNews : ArrayList<NewsDBModel>
    private lateinit var ref : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        bind = FragmentFavsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return bind.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        bind.rvFavs.setHasFixedSize(true)
        bind.rvFavs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        arrNews = arrayListOf<NewsDBModel>()
        getFavorites()

    }

    private fun getFavorites() {
        auth = Firebase.auth
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if(currentUser!=null){
            val uid = currentUser.uid
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("favorites").child(uid)


            ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        for(favSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                            val news = favSnapshot.getValue(NewsDBModel::class.java)
                            arrNews.add(news!!)
                        }
                        bind.rvFavs.adapter = FavoritesAdapter(context!!,arrNews)

                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

        }else{
            val intent = Intent(context,Login::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

}
```

Then when I want to delete the item in the cardview, I successfully delete it from the database, but the RecyclerView is not updated.

Also, when I delete an item, that item is deleted, but other items are copied and displayed. I can't understand why.

When the deletion is done, I delete the item from the arraylist and run the notifyItemRemoved() method, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

This is my RecyclerView adapter

```
class FavoritesAdapter(val context : Context, var arrNews : ArrayList<NewsDBModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesAdapter.ModelViewHolder>() {
    val database = Firebase.database
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    val myRef = database.getReference("favorites")

    class ModelViewHolder(val bind: FavoritesRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bind.root){}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModelViewHolder {
        val bind = FavoritesRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return ModelViewHolder(bind)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.bind.txtFavoritesDate.text = arrNews.get(position).publishedAt.toString().trim()
        holder.bind.txtFavoritesAuthor.text = arrNews.get(position).author.toString().trim()
        holder.bind.txtFavoritesTitle.text = arrNews.get(position).title.toString().trim()

       

        holder.bind.cardViewFav.setOnClickListener {

            auth = Firebase.auth
            val currentUser = auth.currentUser
            val uid = currentUser!!.uid
            myRef.child(uid).child(arrNews.get(position).key!!).removeValue()
            arrNews.removeAt(position)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)

         

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrNews.size
    }
}
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: The idea behind the solutions above will also work in the case of the Realtime Database. However, when using notifyItemRemoved(position), are you sure you have the correct value?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for your answer. I'm using Realtime Database.I'm sure I have the correct value when using notifyItemRemoved(position). I also tried the notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyItemRangeChanged() methods but nothing changed.

Comment: Also, when I delete an item, that item is deleted, but other items are copied and displayed. I can't understand why.

Comment: Try to implement one of the mechanisms that exist in those articles. Each one of them has a repo on Github.